# Get product id only from load order condition

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, collection-filtering

I am working on order collection module. I want only product id after load particular order. This is my query,

```
$ordered_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrment_id);
```

Is there any function which gives only product id only. Not a big array of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$ordered_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrment_id);
$orderedItems = $ordered_items->getAllVisibleItems();
$orderedProductIds = [];

foreach ($orderedItems as $item) {
    $orderedProductIds[] = $item->getData('product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ordered_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrment_id);

foreach($ordered_items->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
    echo $item->getProductId()
}
```